# find users with gps

Tags: android, dictionary, gps

I need to create an application that will show me on a map to all users who have installed my app within x distance.

It wondered if I need to save the coordinates of each user periodically in a database and read the position or is there another option

Answer (score 2):

Tracking the user's location in a database will likely be your easiest option.  It will also scale well.  If you are only tracking a couple users, you could use another simpler data storage mechanism like an XML file, a text file, or even some sort of Application Level Variable.

I'm sure that you have done some research on how best to track your users, but [this](https://github.com/yyl/Tracking-map-on-android) is a pretty good starting point, if you don't have one already.  They are storing each location in a local database on the phone, so I'm sure that you could very easily modify it to send that same location to a web service or something.